# SilverStripe FulltextSearch causing database error

Tags: silverstripe

I'm following this tutorial:
 https://www.cwp.govt.nz/guides/core-technical-documentation/framework/en/tutorials/4-site-search

I've finished the first step of adding `FulltextSearchable::enable();` to `mysite/_config.php`. I then run the `dev/build` as suggested but instead of completing successfully, I get this error:

> [User Error] Couldn't run query: ALTER TABLE "File" ADD fulltext
>   "SearchFields" ("Filename","Title","Content") The used table type
>   doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Google tells me that my MySQL database is in the incorrect format. However SilverStripe automatically generates a database for you. I could change the database format, but I don't think changing the database format is the correct approach here as other users appear to have the module working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my memory serves me right SilverStripe creates the tables as InnoDB. [MySQL 5.5 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) says that `FULLTEXT` indexes are supported by MyISAM tables. InnoDB support for `FULLTEXT` indexes comes in 5.6.

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.)

You need to change your tables to MyISAM or update MySQL.

[Here](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/innodb-to-myisam/) is a good guide for changing table types. In case the site goes down, here are the good points:

> Steps to follow:
>
> - **Take backup of Mysql database.**
> - Run this sql query via terminal or in phpmyadmin for the database which you wish to convert into MYISAM.
>
>   `mysql -u username -p -e "SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME,' ENGINE=MYISAM;') FROM Information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND ENGINE = 'InnoDB' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'" | tail -n+2 >> alter.sql`
>
>   Note: Change `db_name` with your actual database name
> - Import that alter.sql file into INNODB database

EDIT: Of course you can only change those tables that need to be `FULLTEXT` indexed.